# @for loop in Razor

Tags: c#, razor

I have a foreach loop `@foreach (var t in Model)` how I can transfer it to @for loop? And I need browse elements from the end. Example: if I have array {1,2,3} I need display it like   3,2,1

Comment: Just write a `for` loop - what's the problem? Perhaps you should show the code for `Model`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for(var i = Model.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't Razor need curly braces for that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a horribly worded question.. but here's a little pity code.

add your own Razor markup as appropriate...

```
if ( (null != Model) && (0 < Model.Count) ) {
    for (int index = Model.Count - 1; 0 < index; index--) {
        // show some Model[index] goodness...
    }
}
```